# Nbgrader with Littlest JupyterHub releases assignment to course directory but not to /srv/nbgrader/exchange

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-console, nbgrader

#### Operating system

#### `nbgrader --version`: 0.6.1

#### `jupyterhub --version` (if used with JupyterHub): 1.0.0  (Using littlest Jupterhub)

#### `jupyter notebook --version`

jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.2
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.2
jupyter lab      : 1.2.8
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3

#### Expected behavior: When used

> nbgrader release_assignment ps1 --force --debug

It should release the assignment in /srv/nbgrader/exchange shared folder.

#### Actual behavior

I am facing an issue when I try to release the assignment:

nbgrader release_assignment ps1 --force --debug

It releases the assignment without errors but to the location (/home/jupyter-tljh-admin/course_id/outbound/ps1) but not to the shared location /srv/nbgrader/exchange:

[ReleaseAssignmentApp | INFO] Overwriting files: /home/jupyter-tljh-admin/course_id ps1
[ReleaseAssignmentApp | INFO] Source: /home/jupyter-tljh-admin/course_id/release/./ps1
[ReleaseAssignmentApp | INFO] Destination: /home/jupyter-tljh-admin/course_id/outbound/ps1
[ReleaseAssignmentApp | INFO] Released as: /home/jupyter-tljh-admin/course_id ps1

The folder /srv/nbgrader/exchange has write permissions.

Please suggest, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. When I opened the Formgrader there was a notification saying that the directory `/srv/nbgrader/exchange` does not exist or could not be created. I simply created the directory on my own, but not directly. First I created the directory `/srv/nbgrader` with `sudo`. Then I `cd` into that directory and created the subdirectory exchange, also with `sudo`. I also added a `nbgrader_config.py` in `/etc/jupyter` with the following content:

```
from nbgrader.auth import JupyterHubAuthPlugin
c = get_config()
c.Exchange.path_includes_course = True
c.Authenticator.plugin_class = JupyterHubAuthPlugin
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the `/srv/nbgrader/exchange` directory and add the permissions like this: `chmod ugo+rw /srv/nbgrader/exchange`
2. Open the `nbgrader_config.py` that was created after running `nbgrader quickstart <course-id>`
3. Make sure these two lines are present and uncommented:

```
    c.CourseDirectory.course_id = "<course-id>"
    
    c.IncludeHeaderFooter.header = "source/header.ipynb"
```

4. Search for the specific line that says: `c.CourseDirectory.root = ''`, ***uncomment*** it, and set it to `c.CourseDirectory.root = /full/path/to/your/course-id/`
5. Search for the specific line that says: `c.Exchange.assignment_dir = '.'` and actually set it to `c.Exchange.assignment_dir = '/srv/nbgrader/exchange'`
6. Copy this exact `nbgrader_config.py` into `.jupyter` or any other directory that apprear in `jupyter --paths`
7. Stop and restart your server